# Why is pandas.to_csv dropping numbers when trying to preserve NaN?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

Given a pandas dataframe

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([(290122, 0.20, np.nan),
                    (1900, 1.20, "ABC")],
                     columns = ("number", "x", "class")
                  )

     number    x class
 0   290122  0.2   NaN
 1     1900  1.2   ABC
```

Then exporting it to a csv, I would like to keep the NaN, e.g. as "NULL" or "NaN",

```
 df.to_csv("df.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False, na_rep="NULL")
```

Yet, opening the csv I get the following:
That is, the last two digits of number in the first cell are dropped.

[image]
Here is the output opened in text editor:

```
 number,x,class
 2901,0.20,NULL
 1900,1.20,ABC
```

As mentionned, when dropping the na_rep argument, I obtain as expected:

```
 number,x,class
 290122,0.20,
 1900,1.20,ABC
```

Comment: It's an Excel cell problem, not Pandas. Either open your csv in text editor or widen the cell in Excel. Nothing is dropped.

Comment: No, it is also not there when opening with text editor. Besides, it works as expected if I remove the "na_rep" argument

Comment: If you're sure then this represents a bug. Post it on https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues  as a bug report.

Comment: To be honest.... I cannot reproduce your issue. Everything works as expected. Pandas 1.0.1 here.

Comment: I use python 3.7.6, pandas 1.0.0 and numpy 1.18.1

Comment: Using these version I can reproduce  your problem ;)  Feels like a bug, but I'll investigate a bit more and get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is in fact a bug in pandas 1.0.0.  Fixed in 1.0.1. See release notes and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25099.

Depending on you data a quick work around could be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

na_rep = 'NULL'
if pd.__version__ == '1.0.0':
    na_rep_wrk = 8 * na_rep

data = [(290122, 0.20, 'NULL'), (2**40 - 1, 3.20, 'NULL'), (1900, 1.20, "ABC")]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=("number", "x", "class"))

df.to_csv("df.csv", encoding="utf-8", index=False, na_rep=na_rep_wrk)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df.csv', keep_default_na=False)

assert(np.all(df == df2))
```

This gives the csv file:

```
number,x,class
290122,0.2,NULL
109951162777,3.2,NULL
1900,1.2,ABC
```

Answer (score -1):

In .csv files, when reading or writing from pandas - np.nan is stored in file as '' (empty-string), so dont use na_rep='NULL' and instead when reading from pandas again (after saving), do this:

```
for col in df.columns:
   df[col].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == '' else x)
```

Although, all empty strings are read as NaN by default. This is still useful - just to be safe.

I have faced this issue myself before and found that there's just no other way to fix this, but if I do find one (saving nan or NULL flawlessly), I'll update here.